# Animated array modifier and scaling

Tags: animation, modifiers

I want to create an animation of a wing deploying to this position:[image]

From a position where all of the "feathers" are pointed straight down:
[image]

I am using an array modifier with an empty for the scale and rotation of the feathers, and when I change the rotation of the empty to put the feathers in the back position, they change their shape.

Is there some way that I can maintain the size and shape of the feathers when I rotate the empty?

Comment: if you don't scale the empty, the instances should not scale

Comment: if he doesn't scale the empty, the meshes won't be scaled -> but that's what he wants ;), that's why i think the array modifier might not be the right solution here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would give GN a try:

[image]

The mix color nodes is used here to drive the animation from zero rotation to the "right" rotation. Animated is just the factor from zero to one.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine with an object-offset array around an Empty.The transform from array element 1 and the Empty will be recursively applied between elements 1 and 2, 2 and 3, and so on.

Here, the Empty and element 1  share an origin in XY. The Empty is slightly down in Z. The Empty is scaled along its local X. The X axes start out aligned.

[image]

As the Empty is rotated about the common local Z, the blades are splayed. But [GN is a more flexible solution here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/264834/35559). You have no control over the shape of the wing using an array, in which each blade must be a constant scale of the previous one.